# File Upload in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

When uploading pictures to eBay selling it opens up in File Upload. This shows the pictures in thumb nail form and is impossible to make out.
In Windows it opens up direct to my pictures.
Is there a way to make the thumb nails bigger so i can see what to upload ?
Using Cinnamon Mint 20.3 with Intel NUC
Any help appreciated as am dragging and dropping at present which is not ideal
.
Thank you , Ted

Comment: What is "File Upload"? Can you show us a screenshot? What browser do you use?

Comment: I use Firefox. Sorry not sure how to upload a picture on this site.it says at the top File Upload and to the left all the photos in thumbnails. The photos are also in pictures which is how I have been dragging and dragging into the eBay photo uplift boxes

Comment: I am not sure if new users are allowed to upload, but if not, you can upload directly to https://imgur.com and then post the link here and we can edit it in for you. I am trying to understand if this "File Upload" thing is part of the ebay website or if it is part of firefox itself.

Comment: OK, I found what you mean, it is firefox's open file dialog. When you click on an image, don't you gate a large view of it on the right hand side?

Comment: No, I have expanded the view to check that.

Comment: By the way thank you for replying.

Comment: That seems really strange. I am testing it right now (Firefox on cinnamon, different Linux distribution but that shouldn't matter) and this is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/6duvDB9.png. Clicking on an image loads it on the right hand side. The image needs to be selected, but I can't even make the dialog small enough for the preview to disappear.

Comment: Ok. On the left side there is a very small picture ,thumbnail, not like your picture which shows something different.

Comment: Please add some screenshots then because I can't reproduce this. Make sure to also tell us what version of firefox and please actually [edit] all this into your question since comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning.

Comment: When I click on a thumbnail I then select open ,bottom right hand corner, to upload the picture to eBay.

Comment: Ok. Will try to upload picture.

Comment: Please also tell us what format the images are in and if this happens irrespective of the format.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have decided regretfully that at 83 years old I will not cope too well with Linux. So sadly back to Windows 10 which I am familiar with. Thanks again Terdon for your time. All the best. Ted.

Comment: Oh, that's really unfortunate! You have my respect for being open to trying it and, frankly, if you've gotten as far as being able to upload stuff to ebay, I don't quite buy that you're not up to it. Don't sell yourself short! That said, I completely understand how hard it is to learn new things, and it certainly gets no easier with age, so I wish you luck and do come back and ask again if you decide to give it another try,

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments Terdon plus you have solved my problem. I gave it some thought after reading them and noting it is a Firefox generated page. So I downloaded a different browser Opera and it works fine in that. I can now see the large picture on the right.

Comment: So thank you again.